# UTXO MODEL in Bitcoin

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Well i have some questions regarding the UTXO model -

1) How is it decided how many transactions will a block contain? Are these transactions related in any sorts?

2) Where are the details of sender and recipient of a transactions stored? If they are not stored, how is it decided where to transfer bitcoins?

Comment: Bitcoin stack exchange might be better for you to ask a blockchain specific question https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

1) Miners will usually fill the next block with as many of the highest paying (by fee rate, satoshis/kb) valid (not spent already and pass validation checks) transactions as they can. That way they maximize the transaction fee that they are paid if they win the block reward. There is a limit to the number of bytes a block can contain and it is calculated based on a maximum block weight of 1M virtual bytes, see [Weight Units](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Weight_units), and is theoretically slightly less than 4MB.

2) They are stored in the transactions which are stored in the blocks. By details all that is stored is the scripts, for the sender, the input script (previous output's scriptPubKey and scriptSig), and for the receiver, the output script (scriptPubKey). See [Transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

1> Transactions are broadcasted by anyone in the system and at random intervals. Which transactions, of all the ones broadcasted, are included is very dependent on the miner, as he/she is the one who groups them up and includes them in the block. As Nate noted below, there is also a 1MB block size limit which limits how many transactions can be included in a block. This limit is to prevent huge blocks that clog the network and may be removed if the number of transactions in the network ever grows such that the limit is a serious factor.

2> Sender and recipient transactions are stored in the Blockchain Blocks.Transaction data includes scripts used to spend cryptocurrency amounts listed in the transaction data. The most common of these scripts specify what is commonly called an "address" but that is derived from a public key and is nowadays usually unique to a transaction. It is designed to be difficult or impossible to identify a sender or recipient from these "addresses".

If it is not stored then the transaction will not happen.